# Multiple heat sources on the same object, conduction only

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

If we have a bar of steel "AB" (or any type of material) exposure to a heating source (100 celsius for example) from the "A" end, assume conduction heat only.
Now, I added a second heating source on the same end "A" (100 Celsius also).
the resultant temperature on "A" end would be 200 Celsius or 100?

Comment: If you pour boiling water into a pot of boiling water, does the water then have a temperature of 200℃...?

Answer (score 0):

Placing a cooler object, with no other energy source, into 100 degree heat cannot heat the object to more than 100 degrees, no matter how many heat sources it takes to maintain the 100 degrees.

Answer (score 0):

If the first heat source and the end of the bar it is in thermal contact with are at the same temperature (100 C), they are in thermal equilibriums. In the absence of work the only way to change the temperature is by means of heat transfer to or from them. Heat is energy transfer due solely to temperature difference. If the second heat source is at the same temperature (100 C) heat transfer cannot occur if it is brought into contact with A, and therefore the temperature at A cannot change.

The temperature at A will stay at 100 C.

Hope this helps